# How could Giants sit in public transit?

Tags: fantasy-races, transportation, humanoid

An extension to another [question about public transit and mythical humanoids](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/112002/could-winged-humanoids-perch-on-public-transit).

In the same modern world as proposed, there are Giant humanoids with a decent population of 50,000,000 . But not in the sense of Robert Wadlow, who grew up almost up to 9 feet; but instead they average out 12 feet in height (some can be bigger, some can be smaller).

[image]

**Edit:** Since apparently  people want more specifics of what kind of giants they need to know, I'm imagining they follow the top answer of [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/how-to-make-a-realistic-giant), with additional thicker arms and feet similar to elephant feet.

Considering that there are buses, trains, trams, and cars like our own, possibly slightly more advanced, what could be convenient enough for the giants to go about their lives on public transit?

Comment: Are we assuming that the giants have somehow gotten around the physiological problems created by the square-cube effect? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Being_the_Right_Size

Comment: Is this question about what existing vehicles would be acceptable or how you design e.g. a train that is suited for those people sitting down?  Btw where I come from you don't have to sit down on a train or bus

Comment: @Spencer Oh come on, nothing in fiction makes sense or it wouldn't be fiction. Please need to stop beating people over their head with that thing every time someone mentions the word "giant"

Comment: @Raditz_35 You can't give a good answer without establishing parameters first. Ergonomic design comes from understanding the capabilities of the people being designed for. Can we assume the giants have the same physiology as us, straining the possibilities at 12 feet tall, and not able to stand for extended periods? Or are their bones, muscles, and circulatory systems enhanced somehow?

Comment: @Spencer First, I think you should ask that question differently if this is your true intention which I don't believe. Second, have you read any answers here? I mean I'm someone who always wants very specific information, but I think this goes too far. Nobody is going to deisgn a comfortable chair and neither is this really needed in most fictional worlds, it's gonna be some random stuff about large chairs or chair-like objects on some truck or whatever

Comment: @Raditz_35 Please remember to [be nice](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) and to, perhaps particularly in this case, assume good intentions.

Comment: if those 50 million giants were taking part in the evolution of mankind, somehow managed to survive 'regular' human dominance, and take part in everydays life, *everything* would have been designed to suit them, as part of product design evolution...no?

Comment: 50 million out of 7.6 billion means there are less than 2.5M giants (less than 1% of the population) in each of the US and Europe, and that they are sufficiently different to be -- before 40ish years ago -- feared for their power and shunned except in time of war.  Or else they've become the masters.

Comment: @user535733 "like our own" doesn't mean the exact same as you think. I also said "possibly" slightly more advanced, meaning things changed for the different humanoids.

Comment: I assume you're looking for an answer more sophisticated than "open topped vehicles

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm. It's hard for my mind to keep from imagining a bunch of giant go-carts on the highway, Mario Cart-style. More to the point, with most vehicles the design could be more-or-less the same as human cars, but with reduced space for passengers. An SUV-sized vehicle might only seat two giants (including the driver), for example. A giant family (re: a family of giants) might have to take a minimum of two cars when traveling anywhere.

I could imagine buses and subways having special seats dedicated to giants and charging giants an extra fee for the extra space. Because of that, I would imagine specialized taxis would be a lot more appealing for the Goliath on the go. Alternatively, maybe they have their own bus system or get picked up for work with flatbed trucks. I guess if would all depend of what percentage of the population are giants.

All of these have the issue of being expensive for the average giant consumer. Maybe only more prosperous giants move to cities? Or perhaps cities in this world cater to pedestrians more than our own cities. After all, with there massive stride length, a giant could probably walk at 6.0 mph without much effort. Just make sure the city planner puts the giant district right next to where giants work (docks? warehouses?). Maybe a giant could use a specially constructed bicycle/quadracyle.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more of an economics question, and the answer depends on how common giants are. Modern manufacturers design their products to accommodate the vast majority of their target market, in a one-size-fits-all approach. Think of this question: what would vehicles look like if many of us were hobbits?

50 million giants worldwide would probably end up rather marginalized. Perhaps one subway car per train would have the seats and bars ripped out for them. Niche small businesses would customize semi trucks for giants, and safety laws would limit how large a scrap metal motorcycle can get.

If giants are common enough, vehicle cabin sizes would get bigger, as would everything else. Train tracks, car lanes, and airport runways would be wider. Car doors and subway seats would have fold-out steps or ladders for wee humans to climb up, and safety features like seatbelts would have to be more flexible. Humans would be more comfortable in sub-compact cars, but they'd still have to scoot the seats way up to reach the pedals. Here, specifically sized products would only be common where necessary (e.g. clothes, chainsaw grips, tableware, door handles). Niche vehicle markets might be possible, but would necessitate special safety requirements: human-size motorcycles would have to be incredibly sturdy to meet crash safety ratings, proportionally huge bumpers, etc.

While this would finally make the Starbucks Venti size reasonable, I refuse to sit in a booster seat at restaurants. That's just degrading.

Answer (score 0):

As a real-life "giant" in public transport, i would say that your giants would not fit in modern trains or buses without making them unwieldy or impractical to 'regular' humans

As an alternative to getting on the bus, i would suggest that your giants get *on* the bus: make seat cushions and foldable backrests on top of the reinforced) roof of the cars